# How to create dropdown list from a json array in a function in HTML with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

There are about fifty entries, I know I should also have some iterator so that I can keep pulling task after task and autofilling the dropdown list. I'm having trouble even thinking about how to start it, i was talking to someone about dynamically populating, I'm not sure how to start in my scenario.

```
function table_generate_from_json(array,table_id){
  table_html=""
  function create_table_row(item,index){

    $("td[field='task_name']").html(html_link_from_todoist_task_dictionary(item))
    $("td[field='task_priority']").html(item.type)
    $("td[field='task_due_date']").html(moment(item.due_date_utc).fromNow())
    $("td[field='task_created_date']").html(moment(item.date_added).fromNow())
    $("tr").attr('id',item.id)
    table_html=table_html+$(table_id).html()
  }
  array.forEach(create_table_row)
  $(table_id).html(table_html)
}

//todoist_table_list
function todoist_task_list_generate(array){
  table_generate_from_json(array,'#todoist_table_list_tbody')
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use this as sample**

```js
 var json_a=[
    {
     user:"user1hp",pass:"pass1"
    },
    {
     user:"rexuser2",pass:"pass2"
    }
    ,
    {
     user:"rexuser3",pass:"pass3"
    }
    
    ];
    let l=0;
    l=json_a.length;
    let i=0;
    let select=document.getElementById("sel");
    for(i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = json_a[i].user;
    opt.innerHTML = json_a[i].user;
    select.appendChild(opt);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>JSON ARRAY LIST</title>
</head>
<body>

<select id="sel">
</select>

</body>
</html>
```